# ReactJs Form Submit on Enter Key press

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I want to submit my form when the enter key is pressed but if i use `onSubmit={() => this.onSearchClick(this)}` which is my function i need to run all it does it put the form into the url which i dont want to happen all i need to do is make it run that function which will do an api call.

my code is this

```
<form>
      <h1>Search</h1>
      <hr />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Case ID" name="caseid" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Title" name="title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Forename" name="forename" value={this.state.forename} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Surname" name="surname" value={this.state.surname} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Postcode" name="postcode" value={this.state.postcode} onChange={this.handleChangePost} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Telephone Number" name="telephone" onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      <TextField floatingLabelText="Email Address" name="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
      <br />
      {this.state.isLoggedIn ? <RaisedButton label="Search" onClick={() => this.onSearchClick(this)} primary={true} /> : <RaisedButton label="Search Disabled" primary={true} />}
       &nbsp;&nbsp;
       {this.state.isLoggedIn ? <RaisedButton label="New Entry" onClick={() => this.gotoNew()} primary={true} /> : <RaisedButton label="New Entry" primary={true} />}
</form>

onSearchClick = (value) => {
    this.setState({
        loading: true,
        searchQuery: value,
        showCourtesy: false,
    }, function () {
        this.doSearch();
    });
}
```

which calls this

```
doSearch() {
    this.setState({
        loading: true,
        showCourtesy: false
    }, function () {

    });
    var search_url = "http://10.0.2.31/testwebapi/api/data?"
        + "forename=" + this.state.forename
        + "&surname=" + this.state.surname
        + "&caseid=" + this.state.caseid
        + "&postcode=" + this.state.postcode
        + "&telephone=" + this.state.telephone
        + "&email=" + this.state.email
        + "&title=" + this.state.title

    var _this = this;
    this.serverRequest =
        axios
            .get(search_url
            )
            .then(function (res) {
                _this.state.searchResults = res.data;
                _this.setState({
                    loading: false,
                })
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                window.alert("Unauthorized To Access This Please Contact IT If You Believe You Should Be")
            })
}
```

Comment: You need to put `event.preventDefault()` in the submit listener, and pass the event object as an argument, e.g. `onSubmit={ e => { this.onSearchClick(this); e.preventDefault(); }}`

Comment: @pawel do i put that on the input or the form?

Comment: @andywilson `onSubmit` listener goes on the `form`.

Comment: @pawel perfect please make this an answer and I will select as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the form `submit` event from redirecting you need to call `event.preventDefault` method.

You can add it in-line, like this:

```
<form onSubmit={ e => { this.onSearchClick(this); e.preventDefault(); }}></form>
```

Keep in mind the above, just like your original code, passes a reference to the component to `onSearchClick` method, but from your code it looks like the method expects a string. But this is outside of the scope of this question.

You can also refactor your `onSearchClick` method to accept an event as the first argument:

```
onSearchClick = ( event, value ) => {
   this.setState({
    loading: true,
    searchQuery: value,
    showCourtesy: false,
    }, function () {
        this.doSearch();
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}

<form onSubmit={ this.onSearchClick.bind( this ) }></form>
```

Again, the `value` will not be passed. I would recommend to use `refs` to keep a reference to the query input field, so value would be `this.refs.query.value`.

Comment: Arrow functions do not need bindings as they are automatically bound to the `this`. See 'Best Solution: ES2015 Arrow Functions' https://medium.com/komenco/react-autobinding-2261a1092849

Comment: @Purgatory You're right (well, not only they do not need `bind`, they can not be bound to another context). From the code I thought it's defined as a method of the component and missed it's `=` instead of `:` after function name. Otherwise I don't know what's the `this` to which the method is attached, may as well be the global object.

Comment: Agreed, yes I was under the belief that the `onSearchClick` function was in a `Component` class context, in the case that it is then it is safe to do `onSubmit={this.onSearchClick}` however your solution above will work in both contexts.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form onSubmit={() => this.onSearchClick(this)}>  ....

onSearchClick(event) { 
    event.preventDefault() 
    /* do stuff here */ 
}
```

The event.preventDefault() function will prevent the form from interacting with the browser and allow you to make internal API calls, etc.

Comment: In this case `this` is not an `event` object and will not have the `preventDefault` method.